# I want to count more than one field of a table in ms access 2007 using query

Tags: ms-access

I have a table named attendance with field name 
Employee_name,Mont,1stDay,2ndDay,3rdDay and so on till 31stDay with yes/No datatype
at the end of month how i count that how many days an employee present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Access is very rusty but something like this should work:

```
SELECT Empoyee_name, [month], IIF(1stDay, 1, 0) + 
                              IIF(2ndDay, 1, 0) + 
                              IIF(3rdDay, 1, 0) + 
                              …
                              IIF(31stDay, 1, 0) AS DaysPresent
```

Comment: You should consider changing your db design to an employee table and a table recording the presence for each day & employee in an extra row. Apart from that, the above select statement could be simplified a bit to something like: select employee_name, [month], abs([1stday]+[2ndday]+...[31stday]) as dayspresent from your_table

Comment: [ABS function](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Abs-Function-dc5340bb-b65f-4fc3-99cf-f4636dab9563?ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU)